# Dell Poweredge SC1435 Hard-Disk failover...what is that?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge

I don't think this server has RAID...or does it? In the BIOS you have an option for Hard Disk Failover...what does that do? Is that RAID1?

Does anyone have any ideas on this one? There is no RAID card in the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it just means it will boot from a second drive attached if the first one can't be detected. This has nothing to do with RAID.